# How to keep user typed dates within this format "yyyy/MM/dd" and within actual calendar dates

Tags: java, date, exception, calendar, formatting

I'm trying to make it so the user cannot type an invalid date. For example, if the user typed in 2017/03/15 it would throw an error and alert the user that this is invalid (keeping the user bound to current and past dates), or would throw an error for any of the following examples Mar 15 2016 (<-although if anyone had advice to get that to work that would be great), 2016/03/151, 2016/15/03, etc. Then I want to able to parse this into an integer without the time (Hours, Minutes, Seconds). Below is my attempt at making this happen...

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

private void addDVD() {
        ConsoleIO con = new ConsoleIO();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date testDate = null;

        boolean alive = true;
        while (alive) {

            String date = con.readString("Please enter Release Date. (yyyy/MM/dd)");

            try {
                testDate = sdf.parse(date);
                alive = false;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                con.print("Incorrectly typed date. Try again please. (yyyy/MM/dd)");
            } 
            if (!sdf.format(testDate).equals(date)){
                con.print("The date you provided is invalid.");
            }
        }


        DVD dvd = new DVD();

        dvd.setReleaseDate(Integer.parseInt(testDate.toString()));
}
```

Comment: The basic answer is, you can't and you shouldn't. The date classes are simply containers for the number of milliseconds since a given point in time, they have no concept I formatting. You use a DateFormatter as required to for at the values when you need to display them

Comment: Use a DateFormat Ro parse the String to a Date (you may need to format the resulting Date back to a String a compare it to the original to be sure). If you don't want the time, then you should consider using LocalDate instead, it's more complicated to remove the time portion then you're thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new long for the current time.

```
long today = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then use that to flag if the date is older than the current date.

```
if(testDate.getTime() > today) {
    System.out.println("bad input");
}
```